# Transfer files from Virtualbox guest to host in script with smbclient

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos, virtualbox, samba

I'm trying to develop a script that will run on a CentOS 7 machine, but for now I am developing it in a Virtualbox instance (also CentOS 7). The script will be handling several tasks, but the part I'm having trouble with is sending hundreds of large files to a Windows machine (which for now is my pc, or the Virtualbox host).

Two issues:

**A) Sending the files to host.**

Current attempt looks like:

```
find "${FILES_DIR}" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
  if [ ${file: -4} == ".zip" ]
  then
    smbclient //${WINDOWS_IP}/${WINDOWS_DIR} -U ${WINDOWS_USERNAME}%${WINDOWS_PASSWORD} -c "put ${file}"
  fi
done
```

Where WINDOWS_IP is enp0s3.inet, WINDOWS_DIR is a shared folder on host. Problem is I am constantly getting connection refused errors, and I don't know where to go from here.

**B) Confirming file was transferred successfully**

Does smbclient return anything I can use to check if the file was transferred successfully?

Comment: What about using shared folders instead?

Comment: @mdpc Keeping in mind that the use of Virtualbox is only for some local development, I want to keep this script as close as possible to what will run in production. I should also mention I won't have control over system settings or installed packages on the future CentOS machine.

Comment: What happens if you manually do the same `smbclient` call for a single file? Is the failure consistent, or does it only happen for certain files? Or maybe even sometimes for a single file, and sometimes not? Did you check the return code of `smbclient` when a failure happens?

Comment: Don't forget that the `${WINDOWS_IP}` isn't necessarily the IP/DNS hostname/ip combo but is instead the Netbios name.  Check the man page for the `servicename` option of `smbclient` for info.  Or, use the actual IP address.   Also, connectivity may depend on what method of virtualbox networking you are using.  To get as close as you can to "real" I'd use Bridged, or you could virtualize windows and use host-only or internal-only or "nat network" (not plain "nat").

Answer (score 0):

As for (B), my `smbclient` does return an exit code at least for some errors. You can use `$?` in the shell to get the exit code of the last command. An exit code of zero means "ok", non-zero is an error, for the error I provoked the exit code was 1 (but other exit codes are possible, and not all errors might set the exit code).

The "connection refused" error in mention in (A) may have many reasons, it'll difficult to debug this by Q&A. At least provide some information under what circumstances the error happens or doesn't happen, if `ping` to the remote machine works, if you checked the firewall settings, etc.

And BTW, you can also pipe commands into `smbclient`, as in

```
echo "put ${file}" | smbclient "//${WINDOWS_IP}/${WINDOWS_DIR}" -U "${WINDOWS_USERNAME}%${WINDOWS_PASSWORD}"
```

This may or may not help with transferring a large number of files, by avoiding making a new connection each time, if this fails randomly.

And please consider escaping everything properly (I added the quotation marks). We don't know the real values you use, and bad escaping may mangle the host, user or password, and may be the reason for the failure.